# objective C help needed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode7

I am trying to make cheered board which works as long as my number of rows are odd number. in even number it does color 1 for whole second row and color 2 for first row. instead of color1 on first box and color 2 on second box switching back and forth.

[image]

Here is my logic to draw the rectangles(squares). I think there is some issue with that ?

PanelWidth is User input  Per box in pixels size

PanelHeight is user input per box in pixel size

i is number of columns (horizontal)

r is number of Rows (vertical)

```
// Drawing Rectangles
bool switch1 = true;
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    long int positionHor = (panelWidth*i);
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        int positionVer = (panelHeight*r);
        NSRect col1= NSMakeRect(positionHor,positionVer, panelWidth, panelHeight);
        if (_bgEnable) {
            if(switch1)
            {
                [rectColor set];
            }
            else {
                [rectColor2 set];
            }

        }

        else{
            [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0] setFill];
            NSRectFillUsingOperation(col1, NSCompositeSourceAtop);
        }

        NSRectFill (col1);
        switch1 = !switch1;


        if (_BoarderEnable) {
        [boarderColor set];
        NSFrameRectWithWidth ( col1, _boarderWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you determine what color to draw in

```
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) 
{
  …        
  if (_bgEnable) 
  {
    if(switch1)
    {
      …
    }
  }
  …
  switch1 = !switch1;
}
```

If you have an even number of rects, `switch` is inverted an even number of times having the same result at the beginning of the next row it had at the beginning of the previous row.

Instead of using a boolean switch you should calculate it:

```
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) 
{
  …        
  if (_bgEnable) 
  {
    if( (r+i) % 2 ) // <-- here
    {
      …
    }
  }
  …
}
```

`%` means modulo with a second argument of 2 it is alternating, since the mod to 2 is 0, 1, 0, 1, … In the first column `r` is zero, so the color alternates for every row.

Comment: You're welcome. However, don't forget to mark the answer as correct for other users.

Comment: i am brand new to this site, so please help mw out asi can't find where i correct it from ?

Comment: You should not correct the answer, but mark it as an correct (accepted) answer. However, it is not important … But some people will become angry, if you do not mark accepted answers that way.